# Apache2 no longer working in Yosemite

Tags: macos, apache

After upgrading OSX to yosemite, my local apache2 server is no longer working.  Running

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

does not give any error, however nothing is running on localhost:80, and nothing is written to the log files in `/var/log/apache2/` either. The log files have not been touched after the upgrade of OSX. However, `system.log` shows:

```
Oct 29 13:27:45 Jeroens-MBP sudo[1210]:   jeroen : TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/private/var/log/apache2 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
Oct 29 13:27:45 Jeroens-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd): Please switch away from OnDemand to KeepAlive.
Oct 29 13:27:45 Jeroens-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.apache.httpd[1213]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

In addition, my `/usr/include` dir seems completely empty after the upgrade, not sure if that is related.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I solved my problem. It seems like the upgrade of apache had disabled `mod_ssl`. To debug apache2 config files in osx, run `apachectl` without any parameters:

```
Jeroens-MBP: jeroen$ sudo apachectl
AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of /private/etc/apache2/other/mobilize.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLProxyEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: "To debug apache2 config files in osx, run apachectl without any parameters" - man that saved me hours of work. Why apachectl doesn't spit that diagnostic info when passing the "start" arg I do not know...